# How to add custom field with HTML code in Magento 2 pagebuilder?

Tags: magento2, page-builder

I created a form to add new blocks in the page builder.

Is there any way to add a textarea, as a new element, where I can add html code?

I have this files:

- app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/ui_component/pagebuilder_accordion_form.xml
- app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/pagebuilder/content_type/accordion.xml

How can I add a field that allows the insertion of the html code?

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest this module instead [Goomento - Magento Page Builder](https://github.com/Goomento/PageBuilder) you can tailor your `new element` in one step at here [create your first widget](https://github.com/Goomento/DocBuilder/blob/master/DevDoc/WIDGETS.md)